# Is reintrepret_cast to char* well defined when the char array is modified?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, c++17, language-lawyer

Consider the following example when receiving an expected message from a socket:

```
struct myData {
    uint8_t type;
    int value;
}

myData readFromSocket(int socketFD) {
    myData data{};
    ssize_t bytes = recv(socketFD, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data), sizeof(myData), 0);
    if(bytes == sizeof(myData))
        return data;
    return myData{};
}
```

In this example it is unclear to me if the behavior is well defined.

According to [reintrpret_cast on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) the behavior is well defined for *examination* since the alignment of char is less strict then that of myData and since the cast specifically is to a char pointer. It is unclear to me if examination is exclusive to reads or if it includes writes to the casted pointer.

5) under explanation:

> Any object pointer type T1* can be converted to another object pointer type cv T2*. This is exactly equivalent to static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression)) (which implies that if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's, the value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules (see below)

and the third point of type aliasing:

> AliasedType is std::byte (since C++17), char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

I have tested similar code to the above without any problems, however since this all comes down to what optimizations the compiler does I find it hard to give an exact example of where this may fail.

[This article](https://adriann.github.io/undefined_behavior.html) mentions that casting in the other direction, i.e. from `char*` to `myData` is subject to undefined behavior and recommends the use of `memcpy()`. My assumption is that this conclusion was reached since the cast is not covered by the type aliasing rules.

However [this mail thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17242523) gives doubt that `memcpy()`, according to the standard, should give that guarantee (see quote below) and without having read the standard I'm inclined to agree since it looks like the same cast is done to `memcpy()` as to `recv()`.

> In the C++ community, the current thinking is that memcpy allows to type pun, but IIRC the C++ standard is actually not even clear as for why this is the case, and in its current writing it might be that there is actually no way.

In any case, if anyone knows anything about this and could shed some light I would appreciate it. My interest in this matter is more academic then practical. I've tagged this with c++17 since that's what I'm working in, insights to other standards are welcome.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, looks like you're missing `(&data)`?

Comment: Even if it's not well defined, it's a common enough idiom that any compiler that broke it would be shunned.

Comment: In principal, it is allowed to `memcpy` over a standard layout class like `myData` which is what `recv` essentially does. But this assumes the the source of the data is ultimately another `myData` in the same program. Anything else assumes the representation of `myData`. Here, `recv` could be getting a data stream from another program. Accounting for things like endienness and how different compilers or configurations could change how `myData` is laid out in memory, then it may not work. The problem is the standard doesn't really account for inter-process communications.

Comment: @Caleth I don't think that applies because the lifetime of `data` is already explicitly started by `myData data{};`. That would be if they were trying to cast a pointer to a `char[]` to a `myData *`.

Comment: @Caleth Assuming you mean the `char`s received over the socket, then if there is a problem it is a bug with the socket implementation and is not related to this question. The example provided has no `char` or `char` array.

Comment: @Caleth Can you elaborate on where this potential is? It can't be in `recv` because it isn't aware of the `myData` type and it can't be in the code shown because we can see that it doesn't happen.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For the purpose of this question it is assumed that the data is still in the same endianess and is correct.
What I'm wondering more is what leeway the compiler has to optimize things in these situations while still adhering to the standard. I realize that it would be stupid for a compiler to optimize this particular situation, but that is beside the point of what is allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ Standard specifies aliasing rules in [[basic.lval]/p8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
> . . .
> — a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` type.

The term ***access*** is specified in [[defns.access]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.access):

> ⟨execution-time action⟩ to read or modify the value of an object

Besides that there is no other rule that states that aliasing works one-way.

So we can conclude that aliasing works both ways and the code is OK.

Note however, that if the object being overwritten contains `const` members, then you should `std::launder` it after overwriting, otherwise the compiler is allowed to assume `const` members to never change.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Are you sure aliasing is safe both ways? Can you please check cppcon 2022 talks about type punning ?

Comment: @Kobi generally in C++, aliasing of compatible types is allowed. In addition, aliasing via a `char` pointer is allowed. There is no type punning involved here.

Comment: @rustyx - Sitting in cppcon 22 in various sessions including fireside - what I understand is that even char* aliasing is not really defined but it works since otherwise nothing would work. Aliasing a (std::byte, char*, unsigned char8) buffer as a complex type is not really defined